# How to transform 32 bit *.lib files to 64 bit *.a files

Tags: c++, c++builder, 32bit-64bit

I am currently porting a 32 bit c++ program (with C++ Builder) to 64 bit Code. The application is linking a 3rd party dll and the 32-bit compiler project contains the associated lib file, as usual.
In 64 bit mode, these ".lib" files need to be transformed into archives with extension ".a". I know there is a conversion tool for that (a simple executable) I have used once successfully a while ago. But I cannot remember the name of that tool. Can someone help me here?

Comment: IMHO, the best method is to rebuild the library files using 64-bit compiler settings.  Many errors can creep up when mixing 32-bit libraries with 64-bit libraries.

Comment: ***these ".lib" files need to be transformed into archives with extension ".a"*** You are most likely going to run into problems attempting to mix compilers even if you could solve the 32 to 64 bit problem. You probably have to rebuild the third party software with the compiler you are going to use for your application.

Comment: @rustyx "*On Windows even in 64 bit mode you'd still need a .lib file.*" - in C++Builder, even on Windows, its 64bit compiler uses `.a` files for DLL imports, see [BCC64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC64) and [MKEXP.EXE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 3):

There is no tool to convert 32-bit native code to 64-bit native code. There also is no tool to convert `cl` libraries (`.lib`) to gcc libraries (`.a`).

Answer (score 1):

If your 32bit `.lib` files are DLL import libraries, you can just create new 64bit import libraries from the DLLs themselves.  C++Builder has a [MKEXP.EXE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B) tool for that exact purpose.

If your 32bit `.lib` files are static libraries, there is no way to just convert them from 32bit to 64bit, they need to be recompiled using a 64bit compiler.